# Mail with DKIM Signature gets T_DKIM_INVALID flag by SpamAssassin

Tags: postfix, dkim, spamassassin, spamd

I've installed a Debian (jessie) box with postfix and spamassassin. Configured and everything works fine.

Except receiving mails with DKIM signatur will produce a flag `T_DKIM_INVALID` even if the signature is valid. See log example below.

After that, opendkim will verify the signature and let it pass.

```
Jan 15 14:18:21 localhost spamd[30697]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:51740 to port 783, fd 5
Jan 15 14:18:21 localhost spamd[30697]: spamd: processing message <id#1234567@mail.gmail.com> for user
Jan 15 14:18:21 localhost spamd[30697]: spamd: clean message (-2.0/5.0) for user in 0.2 seconds, 2572 bytes.
Jan 15 14:18:21 localhost spamd[30697]: spamd: result: . -1 - BAYES_00,FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H3,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_WL,SPF_PASS,T_DKIM_INVALID scantime=0.4,size=2553,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could give this package a try instead: [libmail-dkim-perl](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libmail-dkim-perl)

One of the [walk-throughs](http://www.spamtips.org/p/ultimate-setup-guide.html) linked in the Spamassassin [documentation](http://spamassassin.apache.org/doc.html) points out a hint that I would recommend to follow:

"You should NEVER need to use CPAN on a RPM or DEB based Linux distribution."

Comment: `apt-get install libmail-dkim-perl` on debian/ubuntu solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

This happend because of the missing perl module `Mail::DKIM`. Without that, every mail with dkim signature will *fail* the verification. Even those with correct signature.

You can find futher information about it [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spamassassin-users/201406.mbox/%3C1402101334.4760.78.camel@monkey%3E).

A simple fix is to install the missing module via cpan.

Comment: on Debian-alikes, better say `apt-get install libmail-dkim-perl` according to @derasteralex answer